# variable passing between ajax and controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

**HTML**:

`<input type="text" name="txt_uname" id="txt_uname"/>`

**Ajax**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txt_uname").change(function(){
                 $("#message").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='20' height='20'  /> checking...");
             
 
            var cname=$("#txt_uname").val();
 
              $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"money_c/nameget",
                    data:"txt_uname="+txt_uname,
                        success:function(data){
                        if(data==0){
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#55DF00'>Name Available</font>");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#FF0000' >Name Already taken</font>");
                        }
                    }
                 });
 
            });
 
         });
 
       </script>
```

**controller**:

```
function nameget()
    {
        $name= $this->input->post('txt_uname'); 
        $find=$this->money_m->nameget($name);
        
    }
```

**model**:

```
function nameget($name)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from customer3 where cusname='$name'");
          return $query->result();
    }
```

This code shows nothing as result.I want to pass variable from ajax to controller .Then find the value from model and pass to ajax.And i want show a message like in the code.plz help me....

Comment: where you define `txt_uname` ???? your controller not return anything , check your url and console error!!

Comment: i don't know how to return txt_uname.can you help me..

Comment: Is `cname` = `txt_uname` ???

Comment: yes,...var cname=$("#txt_uname").val();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Jquery correction:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txt_uname").focusout(function(){
                 $("#message").html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' width='20' height='20'  /> checking...");


            var txt_uname=$("#txt_uname").val();

              $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"money_c/nameget",
                    data:"txt_uname="+txt_uname,
                        success:function(data){
                        if(data==0){
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#55DF00'>Name Available</font>");
                        }
                        else{
                            $("#message").html("<font color='#FF0000' >Name Already taken</font>");
                        }
                    }
                 });

            });

         });
</script>

**Controller correction:**


function nameget()
    {
        $name= $this->input->post('txt_uname'); 
        echo $this->money_m->nameget($name);

    }
```

**Model correction**

```
function nameget($name)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from customer3 where cusname='$name'");
      if($query->num_rows()>0)
      {
          return 1;
      }else{
             return 0;
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define variable on JS:

```
var txt_uname = $("#txt_uname").val();
```

Model **(if you need number of rows)**:

```
function nameget($name){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from customer3 where cusname='$name'");
          return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

echo value on controller:

```
echo $this->money_m->nameget($name);
```

It's recommended to use json_encode php function to pass data from server to client, and then later, decode that JSON data with some Jquery plugin.
Use the console panel in chrome or firefox to debug errors.

Answer (score 0):

**On your Controller**

```
function nameget()
{
    $name= $this->input->post('txt_uname'); 
    echo $this->money_m->nameget($name);

}
```

**on your model**

```
function nameget($name)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * from customer3 where cusname='$name'");
      if($query->num_rows()>0)
      {
          return 1;
      }else{
             return 0;
           }
}
```